# How can I give CPU time to MySQL 5.7 server (running as a service under Windows 7)

Tags: mysql, performance

I have the following situations (MySQL 5.7/Windows 7)

- An `alter table` request to add a new column. The existing table size is in the order of gigabytes
- An `insert` request with about 5000 records

They are ***not*** running in parallel, these are just two heavy commands demonstrating the same issue.

In both cases Task Manager shows a negligible percentage of CPU usage although there are no other processes that require CPU time. This make me think that the MySQL server is mostly sleeping and if it could get more time the requests would be finished much more quickly.

I give a screen shot of the command, the Windows clock and Task Manager. You can easily see the command has been running for two and a half hours with about 1% CPU time. It is impossible to predict when it will finish.

How can I give more CPU time to the MySQL server?

[image]

Comment: Windows 7 is somewhat old now.

Comment: In your question it looks like MySQL is actually using memory rather than CPU. It needs memory/ram more than CPU power I expect.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Newer versions can do `ADD COLUMN` will very low impact.